# Force a hidden input to return a fixed value

Tags: python, html, flask

The following is my current code:

```
{% for comment in commentlist %} <!-- Comment section -->
    <h5>
        {{ comment[0] }}
    </h5>
    <h6>Created {{ comment[1].strftime('%d/%m/%Y at %I:%M%p') }} By: {{ comment[2] }}</h6>
        {% if session.username == comment[2] %}
        <form action="{{ url_for('detail', slug=entry.slug) }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
            <input class="form-control" name="commentid" type="hidden">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-default1" type="submit">Delete!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        {% endif %}
    <br></br>
  {% endfor %}
```

When the button it pressed it should return the value of

```
{{ comment[3] }}
```

This value I should then be able to fetch from Flask in the form of

```
request.form.get('commentid')
```

Any ideas of how this could be done would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input class="form-control" name="commentid" type="hidden" value="{{ comment[3] }}">
```